# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'HttpRequest' not found

Tags: php, webservice, base64, restful

Estoy tratando de consumir un webservice al cual tengo que enviarle ciertos datos. Al tratar de ejecutarlo me sale el siguiente error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'HttpRequest' not found

Mi código es este:

```
<?php

$request = new HttpRequest();
$request- 

>setUrl('https://direcciondelaapi/datos');
$request->setMethod(HTTP_METH_POST);

$request->setHeaders(array(
'Authorization' => 'Basic c3lusjhsbh',
'Content-Type' => 'application/json'
));

$request->setBody('{
"id": "imagen base64",
"idReverso": ""
 }');

try {
$response = $request->send();

echo $response->getBody();
} catch (HttpException $ex) {
 echo $ex;

}
?>
```

Comment: Es posible que no tengas instalado el paquete `php_http.dll`, para verificarlo, puedes ejecutar `phpinfo();` (desde un archivo por ejemplo) y buscar el estado de `php_http.dll`

Answer (score 1):

No veo nada malo en tu código.
Dependiendo de la versión de PHP que tengas puede que la extensión correspondiente a esa clase no haya sido incluida, puedes encontrar la extensión php_http.dll  [aquí](https://github.com/stealth35/stealth35.github.com/downloads) (esta tiene que ser para la versión de PHP que tienes)

O incluir la implementación que viene en [este código fuente](https://gist.github.com/twslankard/989974)

Answer (score 1):

Intenta reinstalar la libreria con:

```
$ pecl install -f pecl_http-1.7.6
```

Comment: Esto no provee una respuesta a la pregunta.  En cuanto tengas suficiente [reputación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) podrás [comentar en cualquier publicación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). Es mejor [dar respuestas que no requieran clarificación de la persona que hizo la pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/586/). - [Desde revisión](/review/low-quality-posts/230550)

Comment: Hola Javi,

gracias por tus consejos. Intente ayudar con mi comentario ya que tuve un problema similar y lo pude resolver gracias a esto.
Curiosamente en otras preguntas (en ingles) sugieren la misma respuesta. Inclusive en uno de ellos fue las mas votada.
Aqui puedes verlas:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18579407/httprequest-not-found-in-php/20622350
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22726419/php-fatal-error-class-httprequest-not-found

Comment: Hola @federicoVecco a mi también me ocurre a menudo, Y dado que llevo poco tiempo en la comunidad, aún lo sigo haciendo. No obstante, para que una respuesta sea buena, es necesario dar detalles del como y el porqué de cada una de las cuestiones. Si a tu respuesta, le añades el fondo de la cuestión (reinstala la librería porque...bla.bla), y luego pones el enlace a la otra pregunta, entonces perfecto. Sino esas respuestas aquí se realizan en la zona de comentarios. Como irás observando en el sitio, las respuestas, suelen estar muy documentadas.

Comment: Gracias de nuevo @Javifer2 este segundo comentario me parece mas util que el primero en el que dices que no provee una respuesta a la pregunta, lo cual puede no ayudar al que hizo la pregunta porque puede pensar que lo que dije no es correcto (que puede ser, no digo que no).
Aunque no soy muy activo preguntando/respondiendo llevo tiempo como usuario de StarckOverflow y en este tiempo he visto muchos usuarios que intentan sumar 'badges' en lugar de dar respuestas para ayudar

Comment: Cuando estamos en el procedimiento de revisión, o al menos a mi, solo me da algunas opciones para escoger, y tengo que decantarme por una. No es perfecta ni mucho menos, pero dentro de lo que hay, es la que más puede llegar a explicarse. Las otras no pegan ni con pegamento.